# Xamarin.Forms Set video as splash screen

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, avplayer, splash-screen

I am working on `xamarin.forms` shared project. I am facing problem in setting video as splash screen. I got reference from [here](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/iOS/VideoSplash).

The problem I face is video player is initialized and doing its process and in that time, AppDelegate code returns first. so video is not displayed but its sound is coming. Is there anything I am missing ?

Here I merged `VideoController` and `VideoViewController` of the sample. I only use `VideoViewController` and refer my video from Resources folder in `SetMoviePlayer()` function

The code I tried :

**AppDelegate.cs**

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override UIWindow Window { get; set; }
    VideoViewController control = new VideoViewController();

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            try
            {
                Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

                Window.RootViewController = control;

                //global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
                //LoadApplication(new App());

                //control.VideoCompletionEvent += Control_VideoCompletionEvent;   // Tried to invoke this on video completion but doesn't help. AppDelegate returns value first then this event is invoked.
                Task.Delay(7000).Wait();   // video is 7 seconds long                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("======== "+ex.Message);
            }
            Window.RootViewController = null;
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            return true;
        }
        //private bool Control_VideoCompletionEvent()
        //{
        //    //Window.RootViewController = null;
        //    //global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        //    //LoadApplication(new App());
        //    //return true;
        //}
}
```

`VideoViewController` and `VideoCutter` Files are same as in the link above.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can launch the UIViewControl in AppDelegate in following way, and use a `MessagingCenter` to notify launching the Page in `Xamarin.forms`:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

    Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

    var control = new VideoViewController();

    Window.RootViewController = control;
    Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, object>(this, "ShowMainScreen", (sender, args) =>
    {
        LoadApplication(new App());
        base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    });

    return true;
}
```

And in your `VideoViewController`, send the `MessagingCenter` when you video is finished:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    View = new UniversalView();
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view
            
    NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(7, false, (obj) =>
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<object, object>(this, "ShowMainScreen", null);
    });
}
```

You can put the send action in the `videoCompleteEvent`.

Here I uploaded a sample and you can check it: [LaunchViewController-xamarin.forms](https://github.com/XfHua/LaunchViewController-xamarin.forms)

Comment: Thanks @Jack Hua - MSFT, It worked!! I din't think abount messaging center :)

Comment: You actually need NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(7, true, (obj) to be NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(7, false, (obj), otherwise it will load the main screen every 7 seconds on a loop.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, this line is the problem:

```
LoadApplication(new App());
```

As it causes Xamarin to replace your `VideoViewController` with its own `ViewController`. So you need to put it somewhere else after the video is completed (I see that you have some commented out code for that event).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the MakeKeyAndVisible line after your RootViewController line as shown:

```
Window.RootViewController = control;
Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

It seems like the video is being played in the background.

[Here's a simple example](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/Working_with_images/AppDelegate.cs) to show you how Xamarin Native iOS works as that sample is completely build programmatically (without Xibs/Storyboard changes) so it can help you better understand what you are doing