# How to add video in Splash screen for Xamarin IOS and Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to add an introduction video in app splash screen. IS there any way to implement the video splash screen.

Comment: There are numerous existing questions that address this.  Please search before posting.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185967/how-to-play-a-mp4-video-on-the-launch-screen-when-the-app-loads

Comment: I think you didn't understand or not read the question properly. Please read the question again.

Comment: A splash screen is displayed by the OS while the app is loaded.  It occurs BEFORE Xamarin Forms is even loaded.  There are ways to do this is both iOS and Android, and there are many existing questions about how to implement them.  One of which I linked to.  Google will help you find others.

Comment: You can't add a video to splash screen.You can add a video immediately after the splash screen so it looks the same thing in splash screen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56649595/xamarin-forms-set-video-as-splash-screen/56659347